# On the expansion of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For any natural number $N$ one can write $\binom{N+3}{3}$ in the following way:

$\binom{N+3}{3}=\sum_{i\geq 0}^{N/2}(2i+1)^2$,

where $i=0,1,2,...N/2$ if $N/2$ is an integer, and where $i=1/2,3/2,...N/2$ if $N/2$ is a half-integer.

My aim is to find a similar expression for $\binom{N+k^2-1}{k^2-1}$ with $k$ a general natural number. Can we still write $\binom{N+k^2-1}{k^2-1}$ as a sum of squares (possibly multiplied with some coefficients $c(N,k)$)?

**Some background information.**

This problem relates to the partition of the symmetrized $N$-fold tensor product of the matrix algebra $M_k(\mathbb{C})$ with itself in terms of the symmetrized tensor product on vector spaces.

Any ideas/references would be appreciated!

Comment: I would have written that as $$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor N/2\rfloor}(N-2i+1)^2$$